# How to wrap a text with absolute position on an image?

Tags: html, css

I have a  with a background image and on top of it I have text.

```
<div id="slide-container">
   <span id="textOnPicture" class="textOnPicture">lorem ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Normally the value of span is set by JS. User types some text to the input and span displays that text.

```
textOnPicture.textContent = chosenText.value;
cssRoot.style.setProperty("--chosenPictureText", '"' + chosenText.value + '"');
```

I wanted to have stroke on the text so I created a pseudoelement.

```
#slide-container {
    width: 480px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: var(--random-background-url);/*JS chooses a random picture*/
    background-size: cover;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.textOnPicture {
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--random-text-on-picture-color);
}

.textOnPicture::before {
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.03em var(--text-random-border-color);
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    content: var(--chosenPictureText);/*same text as inside of the <span> tag*/
    position: absolute;
}
```

The problem is the text with an absolute position doesn't wrap and it isn't inside of a picture.

I tried making a stroke with a multiple shadows method but it requires a lot of shadows and it is "lazy solution", the stroke isn't perfect as the shadows are overlaping and also it is using ~0,00001% more memory. Simply I don't like it.

"But why are you creating a pseudoelement?" - you may ask. Because when I apply it to the main text for some reason this stroke is quite big.

I want my pseudoelement to wrap properly exactly the same way as the main text (the main text have to be always on top of the pseudoelement).

Comment: Looks like you forgot to apply `position: relative` to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `position: relative` to the parent span and also `left: 0` to the psuedoelement.

```css
:root {
  --chosenPictureText: "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum";
  --random-background-url: linear-gradient(0, orange, lightblue);
  --text-random-border-color: red;
  --random-text-on-picture-color: blue;
}

#slide-container {
  width: 480px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: var(--random-background-url);
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.textOnPicture {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--random-text-on-picture-color);
  position: relative;
}

.textOnPicture::before {
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0.03em var(--text-random-border-color);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  content: var(--chosenPictureText);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide-container">
  <span id="textOnPicture" class="textOnPicture">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I've tried to solve this for a week or even longer .

And for people who also have similar problem: When I applied these changes it totally doesn't work but you need to only remove "width: 100%" from a main text element.